# Should I put the Ionic Platforms folder into source control?

Tags: android, ios, git, ionic-framework

I am building an mobile App using Ionic Framework, and I had added ios and android platforms. I need to regularly update the ios xcode project so I think I should put the platforms folder into git source control. But after I added them, I found many issues occur with the Git, path too long, etc.

But if I don't add platforms folder into Git source control, then there will be risks if I re-add the platform I need to update all the information again inside XCode.

How do you guys manage

Comment: I'm totally not an expert of xcode... but what are the information updated into XCode. Con't you configure them into config.xml ? or if you can't, script them with a gulp task ?

Comment: Yes I find a place to configure it so the final solution is not to put the `platform` folder to ##Git## source control and make the necessary configuration.

Answer (score 6):

### Final Solution:

- Not to put the `platform` folder into **Git** Source control because it will make the source very big and will cause some errors such as `Path too long`.
- Configure the `config.xml` file under the **Ionic** app root folder so that the **XCode** project will be updated automatically. For example:

Specially notice the **id**, **version**, **name**, **description**, etc., configuration values. With these configured, you don't need to update **XCode** project manually any more.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.diankeda.huaquanquan" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>画圈圈</name>
    <description>
        美丽改变生活。
    </description>
...`

Comment: What do you use in your .gitignore so it doesn't add the /platform folder? Mine ignores "/platform"